# PHP bbcode function mention user

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP code that is using preg_replace on forum posts. I want my users to be able to mention their friends e.g. @john @jane

I am using the below functon to convert BBcode into HTML.

```
    function bbc2html($content) {
  $search = array (
    '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/',
    '/(\[B\])(.*?)(\[\/B\])/',
    '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/',
    '/(\[I\])(.*?)(\[\/I\])/',
    '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/',
    '/(\[U\])(.*?)(\[\/U\])/',
    '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/',
    '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/',
    '/(\[url=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
    '/(\[url\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
    '/(\[size=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/size\])/',
    '/(\[img\])(.*?)(\[\/img\])/',
    '/(\[IMG\])(.*?)(\[\/IMG\])/',
    '/(\[strike\])(.*?)(\[\/strike\])/',
    '/(\[STRIKE\])(.*?)(\[\/STRIKE\])/',
    '/(\[youtube\])(.*?)(\[\/youtube\])/',
    '/(\[YOUTUBE\])(.*?)(\[\/YOUTUBE\])/',
    '/(\[left\])(.*?)(\[\/left\])/',
    '/(\[LEFT\])(.*?)(\[\/LEFT\])/',
    '/(\[CENTER\])(.*?)(\[\/CENTER\])/',
    '/(\[center\])(.*?)(\[\/center\])/',
    '/(\[RIGHT\])(.*?)(\[\/RIGHT\])/',
    '/(\[right\])(.*?)(\[\/right\])/',
    '/(\[JUSTIFY\])(.*?)(\[\/JUSTIFY\])/',
    '/(\[justify\])(.*?)(\[\/justify\])/',
    '/(\[color=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/color\])/',
    '/(\[COLOR=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/COLOR\])/',
    '/(\@)(.*?)/'
  );
  $replace = array (
    '<span style="font-weight: 700;">$2</span>',
    '<span style="font-weight: 700;">$2</span>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<ul>$2</ul>',
    '<li>$2</li>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
    '<span style="font-size: $2;">$4</span>',
    '<img src="$2" style="max-width: 100%;">',
    '<img src="$2" style="max-width: 100%;">',
    '<strike>$2</strike>',
    '<strike>$2</strike>',
    '<iframe width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
    '<iframe width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
    '<span class="left">$2</span>',
    '<span class="left">$2</span>',
    '<center$2</center>',
    '<center>$2</center>',
    '<span class="right">$2</span>',
    '<span class="right">$2</span>',
    '<span class="justify">$2</span>',
    '<span class="justify">$2</span>',
    '<span style="color: $2">$4</span>',
    '<span style="color: $2">$4</span>',
    '<span style="font-weight: 700;">$4</span>'
    );

  return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
```

I want the @username to become bold when used. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using `$4`? Your last regex has only two groups.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are already trying to do this with the last regex. Try this as your regex:

```
'/(@\w+)/'
```

And change the `$4` to `$1` in your replacement string